# Basic List Comprehension

Tags: python

Im trying to do some basic list comprehension such as ...

```
abc = [1, 11, 123, 124, 1234, 1234, 2323124, 12, 1354, 235, 2345]
[ str(x) for x in abc if "1" in x ]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 5):

Like this?:

```
[str(x) for x in abc if "1" in str(x)]
```

Of course this will convert each number to a string twice, so it would be more efficient to do something like this:

```
[x for x in map(str, abc) if "1" in x]
```